# Python: Point Clustering/Averaging

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a detector which returns the detected objects' bounding box centers, it works fine for the most part. What I want to do, however, is to consider 10 frames and not 1 frame to conduct the detection, so that I can eliminate more false positives.

The way my detector normally works is follows:

```
1. Get a frame.
2. Conduct the algorithm. 
3. Record the centers into a dictionary per each frame.
```

The way I thought would help reducing false positives is:

```
1. Set up a loop of 10: 
   1. Get a frame.
   2. Conduct the algorithm. 
   3. Record the centers into a dictionary per each frame.
2. Loop over the recorded points after every 10 frames.
3. Use a clustering algorithm or simple distance averaging
4. Get the final centers.
```

So, I've already implemented some of this logic. I am on step 1.3, I need to find a way to group the coordinates and finalize the estimation.

After 10 frames, my dictionary holds such values (can't paste all):

```
      (4067.0, 527.0): ['torx8', 'screw8'], 
      (4053.0, 527.0): ['torx8', 'screw1'], 
      (2627.0, 707.0): ['torx8', 'screw12'], 
      (3453.0, 840.0): ['torx6', 'screw14'], 
      (3633.0, 1373.0): ['torx6', 'screw15'], 
      (3440.0, 840.0): ['torx6', 'screw14'], 
      (3447.0, 840.0): ['torx6', 'screw14'], 
      (1660.0, 1707.0): ['torx8', 'screw3'], 
      (2633.0, 700.0): ['torx8', 'screw7'], 
      (2627.0, 693.0): ['torx8', 'screw8'], 
      (4060.0, 533.0): ['torx8', 'screw6'], 
      (3627.0, 1367.0): ['torx6', 'screw13'], 
      (2600.0, 680.0): ['torx8', 'screw15'], 
      (2607.0, 680.0): ['torx8', 'screw7']
```

As you can notice, most of these points are already the same points with a bit of pixel shift, which is why I am trying to find a way to get rid of the so called duplicates.

Is there an intelligent and efficient way of dealing with this problem? First thing came to my mind was k-means clustering, but I am not sure if this fits to this problem.

Did anyone have similar experience?

**EDIT:** Okay so I made some progress and I am able to cluster the points using Hierarchical Clustering, because in my case I have no priori knowledge of the number of cluster. Hence, an approximation is required.

```
# cluster now
points = StandardScaler().fit_transform(points)   
db = self.dbscan.fit(points)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(db.labels_)) - (1 if -1 in db.labels_ else 0)
n_noise_ = list(db.labels_).count(-1)

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
        for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = points[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
            markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = points[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
            markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

[image: Clustering Result]

which works great. I am able to eliminate the false positives (see the black dot), however, I still don't know how I could get the average per cluster. Like, after I find the clusters, how can I loop over each cluster and average all the X,Y values? (Before `StandardScaler().fit_transform(points)`, obviously, since after that I lose the pixel coordinates, they are fit between minus one and one.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally, I got it. Since I also would need my points in their original scale (not between -1 and 1) I also had to do rescaling. Anyway, here is the full magic:

```
def cluster_dbscan(self, points, visualize=False):

        # scale the points between -1 and 1
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        scaled_points = scaler.fit_transform(points)

        # cluster
        db = DBSCAN(eps=self.clustering_epsilon, min_samples=self.clustering_min_samples, metric='euclidean')
        db.fit(scaled_points)
        core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
        core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True

        # Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
        n_clusters_ = len(set(db.labels_)) - (1 if -1 in db.labels_ else 0)
        n_noise_ = list(db.labels_).count(-1)

        if (visualize == True):
            # Black removed and is used for noise instead.
            unique_labels = set(db.labels_)
            colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
                    for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
            for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
                if k == -1:
                    # Black used for noise.
                    col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

                class_member_mask = (db.labels_ == k)

                xy = scaled_points[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
                plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
                        markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

                xy = scaled_points[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
                plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
                        markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

            plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
            plt.show()

        # back to original scale
        points = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_points) 

        # loop over the clusters, get the centers
        centers = np.zeros((n_clusters_, 2)) # for x and y
        for i in range(0, n_clusters_):
            cluster_points = points[db.labels_ == i]
            cluster_mean = np.mean(cluster_points, axis=0)
            centers[i, :] = cluster_mean

        # we need the original points
        return centers
```